# How can I label a column with today's date?

Tags: google-sheets

I tried using the following query() in Google Sheets to label my example column `R` with today's date. However, the query() returns to be invalid.

```
SELECT A,R LABEL R now()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be a text inside single quotes like `'my custom label'`:

`"SELECT A,R LABEL R '"   &   text(today(), "MM-DD-YYYY")    & "'"`